# Optimize lucene search performance

Tags: performance, lucene

I have an application that store (title,body) of a news as separate field in lucene document
At search time i need to create a query that boost title over body. (title is more important in search) but it slow down the speed of searching.
An optimization tip show me that I can combine these two fields into one and It absolutely speed up search and indexing, but I loose scoring that i want to catch at searching (boost title over body)

Is there anyway to combine the benefits ?

Comment: Could you provide us with your benchmarks showing unacceptable performance using two separate fields? You probably want two separate fields to disallow phrase searches to overlap different fields, like title:"hello" body:"world" would match the search "hello world" if you had a combined field of title + body, even if no field contained the phrase.

Comment: If you really want to store an field with combined data, look into custom scorers which would allow you to build your own scoring routing using any algorithm (and field) you want. I leave it as an exercise for a real answer to actually write the example code. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to boost title more than body and index them in the same field is to add title's text multiple times.

Or you can use payloads and override Similarity.  See:

http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2009/08/05/getting-started-with-payloads/

I doubt either of these solutions will give you that much of a speed improvement though.

Comment: Yes it absolutely speed things up look at the
http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/ImproveIndexingSpeed
In my case i don't need to store title or body I just want them to be indexed so the best approach would be combine them to speed indexing and searching

Answer (score 0):

You could also try boosting at index time. For example,

```
Document doc = new Document();
Field f = new Field(...)
f.setBoost(10f); // or choose a float value of choice
doc.Add(f);
```

But still unclear on why you have performance problems with searching with search time boosts. Usually no noticeable loss, if any.